# Let only 1 accordion item stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So Im trying to build my small little accordion with some jquery
Everytime I push the accordion they add a class open and remove the class closed.
But now I want a maximum of 1 item open in the accordion. I can't figure out a way to build it inside my code.

I thought maby the else if statement when there is a open class already when you push the button it closes and it add to your current item a open class.

```
var accordion = ".accordion .section";

$(accordion).addClass("closed");

$(accordion).click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $content = $this.find("ul");
    if(!$this.hasClass("closed")){
        TweenLite.to($content, 0.8, {height:0, ease: Power4.easeOut, y: 0 });
        $this.addClass("closed");
        $(accordion).append("closed")
        $this.removeClass("open");
    }
    else {
        TweenLite.set($content, {height: "auto"});
        TweenLite.from($content, 0.87, {height: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut, y: 0});
        $this.removeClass("closed");
        $this.addClass("open");
    }
});
```

Something like this.

Oh and for the (4) behind it, I also try to find a way to count the LI's inside 1 ul but I didn't really worked on that yet.

Small [example](http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/RPXyZd) I have build so far.

Comment: What's wrong with using `slideToggle()` and `siblings()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not trying to close the others. 
After opening/closing the clicked one, traverse up to `.accordion` then select the items, exclude the one that was clicked on, and close them.

```
$(accordion).click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $content = $this.find("ul");
    if(!$this.hasClass("closed")){
        TweenLite.to($content, 0.8, {height:0, ease: Power4.easeOut, y: 0 });
        $this.addClass("closed");
        $(accordion).append("closed")
        $this.removeClass("open");
    }
    else {
        TweenLite.set($content, {height: "auto"});
        TweenLite.from($content, 0.87, {height: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut, y: 0});
        $this.removeClass("closed");
        $this.addClass("open");
    }

    // close the others
    $(this).closest('.accordion').find('.section ul').not($content).each(function(){
        TweenLite.to($(this), 0.8, {height:0, ease: Power4.easeOut, y: 0 });
    });

});
```

I would suggest using CSS animation though, so you only have to toggle classes.